# парсер/грабер сайта. Как выбрать текст из div

Tags: php, html, веб-скрейпинг

Доброго времени суток всем кто читает. Не получается отделить время добавления статьи от категории

```
<div class="pull-left text-muted">
    <time>50 минут назад</time> 
    | новости
</div>
```

Тег "< time >" с его содержимым мне не надо,
нужно только "| новости"
Парсю на phpQuery то-есть только начал. уже пробовал разные фильтры и пересекания. Никак не получается выбрать только текст родительского элемента.
Буду сильно признателен за помощь. За ранее спасибо.

Comment: Тут поиском https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3+%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2+%5Bphp%5D варианты вам не подходят?

Comment: Тут дело в том что я пользуюсь phpJquery а не xPach, спасибо что напомнили о поиске. :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
let tempObj = $('.text-muted').clone();
tempObj.children().each(function(){
  $(this).remove();
});
console.log(tempObj.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pull-left text-muted">
    <time>50 минут назад</time> 
    | новости
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Чет даже не додумался... Но хотелось бы при помощи phpQuery. попробую перенести это на php.

Comment: Рад помочь обращайтесь ))